# How can I fix a octagon FloatingActionButton error?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having a very strange bug in the app I am building. One of my icons get a visual error and it essentially won't load the background of the FloatingActionButton. It seems to be related to where in the Stack the icon is placed.

I've tried switching the two icons in the Stack and that moved the issue over to the other icon so seems it's related to the 4th position in the Stack somehow. But If I add an empty container there (just to try) that doesn't actually fix the issue. I can replicate the issue on virtual devices as well as my actual phone. and it only shows when I've updated the state of the build.

I've uploaded a screenshot of the issue in the actual app here: https://ibb.co/M1fz4z8

this is the Stack that hold the button:

```
Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: (screenHeight / 4),
                width: screenWidth,
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0.0,
                left: -(screenWidth / 2),
                child: ClipRect(
                  child: Container(
                    height: ovalHeight,
                    width: ovalWidth,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft:
                              Radius.elliptical((ovalWidth), (ovalWidth / 3)),
                          topRight:
                              Radius.elliptical((ovalWidth), (ovalWidth / 3))),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment(0.5, 0.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: (screenWidth / 6),
                  width: (screenWidth / 6),
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    heroTag: 2,
                    backgroundColor: mainColor,
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => HistoryScreen()));
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.assessment),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment(-0.5, 0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: (screenWidth / 6),
                  width: (screenWidth / 6),
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    heroTag: 3,
                    backgroundColor: mainColor,
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => InfoScreen()));
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.info),
                  ),
                ),
              ),

            ],
          ),
```

I'm expecting the button to show as it should, right now instead of the circular background it's showing a weird translucent octagon (still showing the child icon though). No error message is displayed.

Comment: I tested your code and it looks normal in iPhone X simulator. What device do you use for testing?

Comment: I can replicate the issue on my iPhone X and in the Android emulator but not in the simulator. It might be that the issue is stemming from some place else than this code perhaps.

Comment: I tested on real iPhoneX and it is still normal. I guess you have some other code which affect the render. Because I just copied your Stack widgets and removed unnecessary parts to make it work. Can you simplify and share the whole widget tree for that screen?

Comment: You're right, I've identified the issue, it's stemming from a Circular Chart plugin that I'm using, if I use the "rounded" corners options for a chart animation this error happens so seems the issue is sitting within the plugin and not actually in my code. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have identified where the issue is coming from. It is actually coming from me using a plugin called Circular Chart, when using the rounded corner options for the chart the issue appears. I've yet to identify what is causing the issue in the source code of the plugin though. Will post if I figure it out.